# Close a message box after some time and redirect to some web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-webpages

I am making a web page in C# and want to show a message box for 5 seconds and redirect the user to login.aspx if the entered information is true.

I have a register page and the user will try to register (email, username and password are required). I have a `string Answer` that if the entered information is ok, the value of the string is `"OK"` else `"notOk"`.

So, how to add a message box telling `"You have registered successfully"` and after 5 seconds, close the message box and redirect it to login.aspx if `string Answer = "OK"`?

EDIT: I found this [SITE](http://is.gd/qrlIQI) here, it was very helpful.
If anyone is interested in @LordTakkera 's last answer, this [SITE](http://is.gd/8UOTwK) explains how to call scripts.

Comment: This is going to be really hard to do from code-behind, since it only runs on post-backs. Could you use some javascript to control the message box/redirect?

Comment: I thought of javascript, but I don't know to check the string from the code-behind in the asp.net code... any suggestions?

Comment: you can use jquery dialog to show temporary dialog. The following link will be useful for you [Jquery Dialog Example](http://jqueryui.com/show/)

Comment: You should have the whole dialog controlled by JS, and then invoke the dialog creator function in your code-behind. In other words, you shouldn't need to check any string in or from code-behind.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @LordTakkera I don't understand, I have a button and if the button is pressed, I check if the information is true and if I put the script on button pressed, wouldn't it run anyway ?

Comment: After you determine "registration success", invoke a script that pops the temporary dialog. That dialog is set up in JS to do the redirect after 5 seconds. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

After registration has been successfully completed in server-side code, redirect to `success.aspx` which displays "You have registered successfully" to the user and has the following script in the markup:

```
<script>
  setTimeout(function() { window.location = "login.aspx"; }, 5000);
</script>
```